# MySql syntax error while trying to create a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table in my database (hosted with godaddy)

when ever I try to create a table in the database it gives me an error

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

So I am trying to create a table like this

```
USE orderformuser

CREATE TABLE `users`(
`user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` char(25),
`password` char(40),
UNIQUE (User_Id)
)
```

However I am getting this error now.. and I just don't know what I am doing wrong

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `users`(
`user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` char(2' at line 3
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add semicolon `;` after `use ...`. `;` is used to terminate lines in mysql.

```
USE orderformuser;

CREATE TABLE `users`
(
   `user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` char(25),
   `password` char(40),
   CONSTRAINT u_pk PRIMARY KEY (User_Id)
);
```

Comment: @HurkNburkS i think `CONSTRAINT u_pk PRIMARY KEY (User_Id)` should best fit in your table. `PRIMARY KEY` are unique indexes.

Comment: According to @John Woo, CONSTRAINT u_pk PRIMARY KEY (User_Id) is the best way +1

Comment: right okay thanks very much! this worked perfectly.. I found out one of my issues was I was using my user account to enter the sql editor not the DB user.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create a blank database orderformuser. 
After you have to entry into this database and try to create the table with your code changed because you have forgot ";" like this:

```
USE orderformuser;
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
`user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` char(25),
`password` char(40),
UNIQUE (User_Id)
)
```